# How to attach debugger to a released xamarin android app?

Tags: visual-studio, android-studio, xamarin, xamarin.android, xamarin.forms

My xamarin released android app works on debug mode but crashes on release mode on Navigation pushasync event. I want to be able to view the log to know what made the app crash in release mode. How can I attach a debugger to the android process through android studio or visual studio?

Comment: In those cases I usually use hook up the device to my computer of USB and use DDMS to view an error coming from the app. You can also add `Console.WriteLine()` statements into the Xamarin.Android project and/or create a `DependencyService` interface to call `Console.WriteLine()` from your Forms project. I am not sure if there is a way to attach a debugger in another way. Hopefully someone will know of a way.